# Is the pandas .apply function vectorised?

Tags: python, pandas

Does the pandas `df.apply(x, axis=1)` method apply the function x to all the rows simultaneously, or iteratively? I had a look in the docs but didn't find anything.

Comment: vectorized functions do not actually apply to all rows simultaneously. Anyway, for some details see the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938318/why-apply-sometimes-isnt-faster-than-for-loop-in-pandas-dataframe/38938507#38938507).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's iteratively:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=["A", "B"])

In [12]: def f(row):
             f.count += 1
             return f.count

In [13]: f.count = 0

In [14]: df.apply(f, axis=1)
Out[14]:
0    1
1    2
dtype: int64
```

Note: Although in this example it doesn't seem to be the case [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) warns:

> In the current implementation apply calls func twice on the first column/row to decide whether it can take a fast or slow code path. This can lead to unexpected behavior if func has side-effects, as they will take effect twice for the first column/row.

The actual for loop (for python  functions rather than ufuncs) happens in lib.reduce ([here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/880de3054c7ce3a6c48e295837207787dc73350f/pandas/src/reduce.pyx#L102)).

Answer (score 0):

I believe iteratively is the answer. Consider this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

# Make a 1000 row long dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((1000, 4)))

# Apply this time delta function over the length of the dataframe
t0 = time.time()
times = df.apply(lambda _: time.time()-t0, axis=1)

# Print some of the results
print(times[::100])
```

> Out[]:
>   0      0.000500
>   100    0.001029
>   200    0.001532
>   300    0.002036
>   400    0.002531
>   500    0.003033
>   600    0.003536
>   700    0.004035
>   800    0.004537
>   900    0.005513
>   dtype: float64