# Why is pandas apply lambda slower than loop here?

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have a pandas dataframe which I'd like to filter based on if certain conditions are met. I ran a loop and a `.apply()` and used `%%timeit`to test for speed. The dataset has around 45000 rows. The code snippet for loop is:

```
%%timeit
qualified_actions = []
for row in all_actions.index:
    if all_actions.ix[row,'Lower'] <= all_actions.ix[row, 'Mid'] <= all_actions.ix[row,'Upper']:
        qualified_actions.append(True)
    else:
        qualified_actions.append(False)
```

> 1.44 s ± 3.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

And for `.apply()` is:

```
%%timeit
qualified_actions = all_actions.apply(lambda row: row['Lower'] <= row['Mid'] <= row['Upper'], axis=1)
```

> 6.71 s ± 54.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

I thought `.apply()` is supposed to be much faster than looping through rows in pandas. Can someone explain why it's slower in this case?

Comment: I don't _know_ for sure, but I _guess_ it's due to the fact that `apply` must construct a `dict` for every row. Meanwhile, your `for` method efficiently accesses the data using `ix`, without constructing any new objects. I believe this only happens when you apply a Python function; applying numpy functions you stay in C-land and things go fast.

Comment: `.apply` is *not* suppose to be faster when iterating over rows. An `.apply` is essentially a for-loop underneath the hood, if you go on axis=1. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938318/why-apply-sometimes-isnt-faster-than-for-loop-in-pandas-dataframe/38938507#38938507)

Comment: @Amadan it constructs a `Series` out of each row, actually, but yeah, same effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apply` uses loops under the hood, so if you need [better performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316) the best and the fastest methods are vecorized alternatives.

No loops, only chain 2 conditions vectorized solution:

```
m1 = all_actions['Lower'] <= all_actions['Mid']
m2 = all_actions['Mid'] <= all_actions['Upper']
qualified_actions = m1 & m2
```

Thanks [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749018/why-is-pandas-apply-lambda-slower-than-loop-here/47749148#comment82458610_47749148) for another solution:

```
all_actions.Mid.between(all_actions.Lower, all_actions.Upper)
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(2017)
N = 45000
all_actions=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(50, size=(N,3)),columns=['Lower','Mid','Upper'])

#print (all_actions)
```

---

```
In [85]: %%timeit
    ...: qualified_actions = []
    ...: for row in all_actions.index:
    ...:     if all_actions.ix[row,'Lower'] <= all_actions.ix[row, 'Mid'] <= all_actions.ix[row,'Upper']:
    ...:         qualified_actions.append(True)
    ...:     else:
    ...:         qualified_actions.append(False)
    ...: 
    ...: 
__main__:259: DeprecationWarning: 
.ix is deprecated. Please use
.loc for label based indexing or
.iloc for positional indexing

See the documentation here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated
1 loop, best of 3: 579 ms per loop

In [86]: %%timeit
    ...: (all_actions.apply(lambda row: row['Lower'] <= row['Mid'] <= row['Upper'], axis=1))
    ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 1.17 s per loop

In [87]: %%timeit
    ...: ((all_actions['Lower'] <= all_actions['Mid']) & (all_actions['Mid'] <= all_actions['Upper']))
    ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 509 µs per loop


In [90]: %%timeit
    ...: (all_actions.Mid.between(all_actions.Lower, all_actions.Upper))
    ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 520 µs per loop
```

Comment: Or just `all_actions.Mid.between(all_actions.Lower, all_actions.Upper)`

Comment: @JonClements - Thank you, I add it to answer. In sample data it is a bit slowier, but difference is only `11us`, so it is approx same.