# Vectorized version of pd.Series.str.contains

Tags: python, pandas

Given two identically indexed pd.Series of strings, what's the most efficient way to check if each element of the first pd.Series is a substring of the corresponding element of the second pd.Series?

Example:

```
s1 = pd.Series(['cat', 'dog', 'ham'])
s2 = pd.Series(['catbird', 'frog', 'hamster'])  

pd.Series([t[0] in t[1] for t in zip(s1, s2)], index=s1.index)
```

yields

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Could you please add some test data?

Comment: What you have done is good. Do you have any specific problem? Like, the code is slow for large series. BTW `str.contains` is a [vectorized string method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods).

Comment: I think good solution, small modification should be `pd.Series([t in v for t, v in zip(s1, s2)], index=s1.index)`

Comment: Does it make any difference in it's efficiency? @jezrael

Comment: @Vishnudev - I was wrong, it is faster, added answer.

Comment: @sophros I added a simple example.

Comment: @Vishnudev No, I just want to make sure I'm not overlooking a built-in or easier way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your solution is good, because also pandas `.str` functions use loops (and working with missing values), so sometimes slowier.

I change solution with small modification - unpacking tuples to variables `t` and `v`, in tested data it is faster a bit:

```
np.random.seed(2020)

N = 10000
s1 = pd.Series(np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_letters), size=N))
s2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_letters), size=(N, 3))).sum(axis=1)

In [82]: %timeit (pd.Series([t[0] in t[1] for t in zip(s1, s2)], index=s1.index))
3.47 ms ± 271 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [83]: %timeit (pd.Series([t in v for t, v in zip(s1, s2)], index=s1.index))
2.89 ms ± 130 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: That seems quite significant @jezrael.

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import string

np.random.seed(2020)

N = 10000
s1 = pd.Series(np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_letters), size=N))
s2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_letters), size=(N, 3))).sum(axis=1)

%%timeit
s1.apply(lambda x: x[0] in s2.loc[x.name, 0], axis=1)
```

> 218 ms ± 8.61 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Maybe not the best approach :)

Comment: Have you measured it? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749018/why-is-pandas-apply-lambda-slower-than-loop-here

Comment: I got `TypeError: ("'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed", 'occurred at index 0')`, for you working?

Comment: @jezrael didn't get to test it sorry. now it's working.