# Jupyter Kernel Dies when I use .apply

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large pandas dataframe (few million rows) that I am manipulating.  The last column I calculate uses the following code:

`df['diff'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.col_a - row.col_b, axis=1)`

It is fifty-fifty if the code runs, and if it does, it takes the better part of an hour.  Is there a way in pandas to better run.  I've started to do some research, I looked at this stackoverflow page ([Why is pandas apply lambda slower than loop here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749018/why-is-pandas-apply-lambda-slower-than-loop-here)), but it is for categorical data.  I've done some research on Vectorized Operations, but haven't found anything that I think will work.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you just computing `col_a - col_b`? That can be done with `df.col_a - df.col_b`.

Comment: You should use: `df.col_a - df.col_b`. The way you are doing this calculation is calculating row by row versus vectorized. You should only use `axis=1` lambda operations if you really must, but no reason to here.

Comment: I way overthought that, ```df.col_a -df.col_b``` worked, thanks y'all.

Comment: @JoeWolf I tested the time difference. It is massive!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're row-by-row way of calculating is more than 5,000 times slower from using a vectorized way on a dataframe of all random integers of shape `(10000,4)`. Avoid  the combination of `lambda` and `axis=1` if all possible and vectorize.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
%timeit df['E'] = df['A'] - df['B']
%timeit df['E'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.A - x.B, axis=1)
df

485 µs ± 10.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
2.48 s ± 45.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) # > 5000x slower
```