# Check which elements of series are substring of a given text - Python, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string

What I am trying to do is:

Given a series with strings, to find all the indexes of the strings,
that are substring of another main string, **in a vectorize manner**.

**The Input:**

```
series = pd.Series(['ab', 'abcd', 'bcc', 'abc'], name='text')
main_text = 'abcX'

# The series:
0      ab
1    abcd
2     bcc
3     abc
Name: text, dtype: object
```

**The desired output:**

```
0      ab
3     abc
Name: text, dtype: object
```

**What I tried:**

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(series)
df_test['text2'] = main_text
df_test['text'].isin(df_test)

# And this of course won't work, since it check if the main string is a 
# substring of the series strings:
series.str.contains(main_text, regex=True)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex, simply use `in`:

```
series[[e in main_text for e in series]]
```

output:

```
0     ab
3    abc
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Comment: Yes but this is not efficient, I want to do it in a vectorize manner

Comment: @Ilan12 you won't be able to do better with pandas, you can't vectorize here

Comment: maybe with apply it would be faster than with regular loop

Comment: No, regular loops are most often faster than apply ;) see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938318/why-apply-sometimes-isnt-faster-than-for-loop-in-pandas-dataframe) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749018/why-is-pandas-apply-lambda-slower-than-loop-here) for example.