# Concatenating Strings and Items from a Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `dframe` and attempted code below.

```
import pandas as pd
dframe = pd.DataFrame({
        
            'A' : [1,2,3],
            'B' : ['Guitar', 'Piccolo', 'Sax']
        })
    
dframe

for item in dframe:
    print(f"{"Mary's favorite number is"}{dframe[0]}{"and her favorite instrument is"}{dframe[1]}")
```

The expected output is a formatted string for each line of the code indicating "Mary's favorite letter is 1 and her favorite instrument is Guitar", "Mary's favorite letter is 2 and her favorite instrument is Piccolo", etc.

However, the code does not seem to produce these results.

Comment: do you want it in dict?

Comment: Could we do a data frame where each line would contain the print statement? @KaviHarjani

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string concatenation. You have to convert column 'A' to string before:

```
out = "Mary's favorite number is " + dframe['A'].astype(str) + " and her favorite instrument is " + dframe['B']
print(*out, sep='\n')

# Output
Mary's favorite number is 1 and her favorite instrument is Guitar
Mary's favorite number is 2 and her favorite instrument is Piccolo
Mary's favorite number is 3 and her favorite instrument is Sax
```

**Update**: to convert `out` series to a dataframe, use `to_frame`:

```
out = out.to_frame('colname')
print(out)

# Output
                                             colname
0  Mary's favorite number is 1 and her favorite i...
1  Mary's favorite number is 2 and her favorite i...
2  Mary's favorite number is 3 and her favorite i...
```

Comment: How would I save the output as a separate data frame? @Corralien

Comment: `out` is already a `Series`, you can add it to your dataframe `df['colname'] = out` or convert it as dataframe `out = out.to_frame('colname')`

Comment: Would like the entire output as a data frame, if possible. Sorry if I did not make that clear.  @Corralien

Comment: out = print(*out, sep='\n')? @Corralien

Comment: No just use  `out = out.to_frame('colname')`. Is it what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that works:

```
df["Sentence"] = df.apply(lambda row: f"Mary's favorite number is {row.A} and her favorite instrument is {row.B}", axis=1)

for sentence in df["Sentence"]:
    print(sentence)
```

Output:

```
Mary's favorite number is 1 and her favorite instrument is Guitar
Mary's favorite number is 2 and her favorite instrument is Piccolo
Mary's favorite number is 3 and her favorite instrument is Sax
```

You could get fancier:

```py
def sentence_maker(name, possessive_pronoun, number, instrument):
    return f"{name}'s favorite number is {number} and {possessive_pronoun} favorite instrument is {instrument}"


for sentence in df.apply(lambda row: sentence_maker("Leela", "their", row.A, row.B), axis=1):
    print(sentence)
```

Output:

```
Leela's favorite number is 1 and their favorite instrument is Guitar
Leela's favorite number is 2 and their favorite instrument is Piccolo
Leela's favorite number is 3 and their favorite instrument is Sax
```

Comment: Just wondering if this is the optimal solution, isn't the loop happening twice?
Once in apply lambda and once in sentence?

Comment: Huh? What is "stence"`? Either way, no, the lambda runs only once.

Comment: I read it uses a loop under the hood https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749018/why-is-pandas-apply-lambda-slower-than-loop-here

Comment: Oh, sure. Looping over a dataframe is a terrible solution, period. Whether it's an explicit loop like OP is trying to use, or using `.apply()`. If OP really needs the kind of performance where the difference between `.iterrows()` and `.apply()` becomes important, then they're kind of screwed because strings can't take advantage of vectorized operations.

Comment: How would I save the output as a separate data frame? @ddejohn

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
        
            'A' : [1,2,3],
            'B' : ['Guitar', 'Piccolo', 'Sax']
        })
    
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(f"Mary's favorite number is {df.A.iloc[index]} and her favorite instrument is {df.B.iloc[index]}")
```

output

[image]

Comment: How would I save the output as a separate data frame? @KaviHarjani