# apply vs nested for loops

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I'm trying to build a dataframe in python that is filled with 1s and 0s, depending on the number in one column:

```
Date        Hour
2005-01-01  1
2005-01-01  2
2005-01-01  3
2005-01-01  4
```

I want to make new columns based on the number in "Hour", and fill each column with a 1 if that row is equal to the value in "Hour", or 0 if not.

```
Date        Hour HE1 HE2 HE3 HE4
2005-01-01  1    1   0   0   0
2005-01-01  2    0   1   0   0
2005-01-01  3    0   0   1   0
2005-01-01  4    0   0   0   1
```

I can do it with this code, but it takes a long time:

```
for x in range(1,5):
    _HE = 'HE' + str(x)
    for i in load.index:
        load.at[i, _HE] = 1 if load.at[i,'Hour']==x else 0
```

I feel like this is a great application (no pun intended) for .apply(), but I can't get it to work right.

How would you speed this up?

Comment: Of course nested for loop is not preferred

Comment: `.apply`, in general, is not faster than a for-loop. `.apply` is a Python interpreter level [for-loop under the hood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938318/why-apply-sometimes-isnt-faster-than-for-loop-in-pandas-dataframe/38938507#38938507)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In pandas loops are not recommended because slow if exist some vectorized solution.

Notice: In function `apply` are loops under the hood too.

So use [`pandas.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) and [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) for add to original `df`:

```
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['Hour'].astype(str)).add_prefix('HE'))
print (df)
         Date  Hour  HE1  HE2  HE3  HE4
0  2005-01-01     1    1    0    0    0
1  2005-01-01     2    0    1    0    0
2  2005-01-01     3    0    0    1    0
3  2005-01-01     4    0    0    0    1
```

Similar function have different performance:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [62]: %timeit df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['Hour'].astype(str)).add_prefix('HE'))
3.54 ms ± 277 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#U9-Forward solution
In [63]: %timeit df.join(df['Hour'].astype(str).str.get_dummies().add_prefix('HE'))
61.6 ms ± 297 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3):

#### `pandas.factorize` and array slice assignment

```
j, h = pd.factorize(df.Hour)
i = np.arange(len(df))

b = np.zeros((len(df), len(h)), dtype=h.dtype)
b[i, j] = 1

df.join(pd.DataFrame(b, df.index, h).add_prefix('HE'))

         Date  Hour  HE1  HE2  HE3  HE4
0  2005-01-01     1    1    0    0    0
1  2005-01-01     2    0    1    0    0
2  2005-01-01     3    0    0    1    0
3  2005-01-01     4    0    0    0    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Even tho it's really similar to @jezrael's answer but, this is also much better, (it's just using `.str` accessor for `get_dummies`:

```
print(df.join(df['Hour'].astype(str).str.get_dummies().add_prefix('HE')))
```

Output:

```
         Date  Hour  HE1  HE2  HE3  HE4
0  2005-01-01     1    1    0    0    0
1  2005-01-01     2    0    1    0    0
2  2005-01-01     3    0    0    1    0
3  2005-01-01     4    0    0    0    1
```

Comment: `this is also much better` ? Why?

Comment: @jezrael I mean just better than his for loop and apply

Comment: Then absolutely agree ;) But slowier as `pd.get_dummies`

Comment: @jezrael That's true but at least better then his

Comment: Loop and `apply` are equivalent. I didn't downvote, btw

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's True

Comment: @jezrael Yeah, did you downvote, Btw wow you got 65 rep on the top

Comment: @U9-Forward - No, I dont downvote, check printsreen above. If downvoting it is orange colored.

Comment: @jezrael That's true

Comment: I downvoted.  If your answer added some benefit to jez's I could understand the copy/paste, but using the string accessor is strictly worse here (and in most cases), so I don't think this answer is useful.  But since it does get the desired output, dv removed

Comment: @user3483203 I understand but i actually didn't but yeah it's too similar tho