# TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list - pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-analysis

I know a similar question has been posted and I have exhausted them all. I have a dataframe with the fields below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1021, 0.00, ["C2"]],
    [1, 1023, 0.00, ["C2"]],
    [2, 1024, 2.00, ["C1", "C4"]]],
    columns=["index", "id", "revenue", "campaign"])

print(df)
```

Resulting in

```
   index    id  revenue  campaign
0      0  1021      0.0      [C2]
1      1  1023      0.0      [C2]
2      2  1024      2.0  [C1, C4]
```

I just want to create a new column 'path': end of path is Null if revenue is 0 and revenue if revenue is >0.. start of the path is 'Start'

```
  index  id    revenue campaign       path
   0    1021    0.00    [C2]       ['Start', 'C2', 'Null']
   1    1023    0.00    [C2]       ['Start', 'C2', 'Null']
   2    1024    2.00    [C1, C4]   ['Start', 'C1', 'C4', 'Revenue']
```

If I do something below it works.. but i have a billion rows to process so doesnt seem efficient.

```
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if(df['revenue'][i] == 0):
        df['path'][i] = ['Start'] + df['campaign'][i] + ['Null']
    else:
        df['path'][i] = ['Start'] + df['campaign'][i] + ['revenue']
```

But if i work at a column level like this it works sometimes but sometimes it breaks with the erroe that i can only concatenate list to a list.

```
df['path'] = np.where(
   df['revenue'] == 0,
    ['Start'] + df['campaign'] + ['Null'],
    ['Start'] + df['campaign'] + ['revenue'])
```

Can someone help me sort this issue? I would be really grateful.

Comment: Use `.str.cat(...)`

Comment: Hi idelaney.. I tried to create one.. but the dtypes i am getting and the dtypes of my original df are coming out different.. i didnt want to mislead and gave up..

Comment: @thealchemist - yeah, that can be a problem. I added one that I think is right.

Comment: @tdelaney: cant thank you enough.. really appreciate your support

Comment: Since `pandas` omits quotes for string elements, it's hard to tell whether a column entry contains a list or a string that looks like the list display (or even array).  And the column dtype will be `object`.  So if there's a chance of mixing, your code has to take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

> ### You can use the python `.extend` list method and the [`pd.Series.tolist`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-tolist/):

`list1.extend(list2.tolist().extend(list3))`

So:

```py
df['path'] = np.where(
   df['revenue'] == 0,
    ['Start'].extend(df['campaign'].tolist().extend(['Null'])),
    ['Start'].extend(df['campaign'].tolist().extend(['revenue']))
)
```

Comment: Hi vendant.. I get a 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable'

Comment: @thealchemist It seems like one of your rows has data that does not match.

Comment: I think that's because `.extend()` actually returns None (it appends to the first iterable the elements of the second iterable, but returns nothing). Even if you run `a = ['Start'].extend(['banana'])` you will see that `a` is None

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your column `campaign` is of mixed types: in the examples you are showing the values are lists, but from the error it looks like maybe somewhere in your dataframe you have a string, and possibly other types as well. That's why the "list addition" is not working, as it expects to add lists as `[list1] + [list2] + [list3]`, but in some specific row the `df["campaign"]` actually evaluates to a string.

One way to go about this is to first try to guarantee that the column (pd.Series) is of a homogenous type. I would do the following:

```
def to_list(item):
    """Maps anything that is not a list to a list"""
    return item if isinstance(item, list) else [item]

df["campaign"]= df["campaign"].apply(to_list)
```

EDIT:

I originally suggested that you should continue by using `np.where()`, but I'm not sure it will work. In the examples of the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), we're only seeing numerical transformations of the existing variables. And also when trying it out with dummy data it's not working.

What I would go instead (after transforming everything to a list) if write a short function and map the dataframe to it.

```
def concat_cols(row):
    if row["revenue"] == 0:
        return ['Start'] + row['campaign'] + ['Null']
    else:
        return ['Start'] + row['campaign'] + ['Revenue']

df.apply(concat_cols, axis=1)
```

This isn't necessarily faster (or even [different than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938318/why-apply-sometimes-isnt-faster-than-for-loop-in-pandas-dataframe) looping through the dataframe, so you might need to experiment with smaller samples.

Comment: Hi Tania.. really appreciate your response.. now i am getting a TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str.. if i take out the '[]' from 'Start' I get a giant string in the path column which is again bad..

Comment: the to_list function actually turns my list into this:  [[, ', C, 1, 1, ', ]] .

Comment: Hi @thealchemist, take a look at my revised answer. I think the `np.where` solution wouldn't work anyhow (at least it didn't for me). The `to_list` function should work... see example df: `df = pd.DataFrame(dict(banana=[['a', 'b', 'c'], None, 1, [], 'c', ['d']]))` 
 (with various data types, just in case you have those in the "campaigns" column) and then `df.banana.apply(to_list)`