# Performing calculations in python using excel values

Tags: python, excel, multiple-columns, rows, calculus

I'm trying to do some calculations in python using an excel with several rows and using 3 columns.
I'm using the columns 'Band' and 'Antenna_Heigh' and I would like to save these values in the column 'Colors'.
My code looks like this but I have an error saying 'list assignment index out of range'.

```
madrid = pd.read_excel('Madrid.xlsx')

ch = []

d=[]
  
L = 8.4

for i in range(0, len(madrid)):

    ch[i] = 0.8 + (1.1*math.log10(madrid['Band'][i]) - 0.7)*madrid['Antenna_Height'][i] - 1.56*math.log10(madrid['Band'][i])

    d[i] = ((L - 69.55 - 26.16*math.log10(madrid['Band'][i]) + 13.82*math.log10(madrid['Antenna_Height'][i]) + ch[i])/(44.9 - 6.55*math.log10(madrid['Antenna_Height'][i])))**10

    madrid['Colors'][i] = d[i]
```

Comment: Use `for i in range(0, len(madrid)):`. Remember that Python's indexes start in 0, not in 1.

Comment: Yes, I started using 0 but i was trying with 1. But I have the same error even if I use 0

Comment: Ok, but if I do `d = []; d[1] = 'foo'`, I get the same error. So, at least, keep the range starting in 0 for assigning values to the lists.

Comment: Do you need to keep the values of `ch` and `d` after generating the 'Colors' column?

Comment: No, just the final value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list `ch` is empty, so calling any element index like `ch[0]` or `ch[1]` will result in error "list index out of range"

I see you're trying to append to the various lists. You can try (but I'm not sure about the formula, please check them)

```
import math

madrid = pd.read_excel('Madrid.xlsx')
ch = []
d=[]
L = 8.4

for i in range(0, len(madrid)):
    ch_temp = 0.8 + (1.1*math.log10(madrid['Band'][i]) - 0.7)*madrid['Antenna_Height'][i] - 1.56*math.log10(madrid['Band'][i])
    ch.append(ch_temp)
    d_temp = ((L - 69.55 - 26.16*math.log10(madrid['Band'][i]) + 13.82*math.log10(madrid['Antenna_Height'][i]) + ch[i])/(44.9 - 6.55*math.log10(madrid['Antenna_Height'][i])))**10
    d.append(d_temp)
    madrid['Colors'][i] = d[i]

print(madrid)
```

Output:

```
   Band  Antenna_Height      Colors
0     1               3   18.262619
1     2               3   62.881852
2     3               3  121.442224
3     4               3  188.948366
4     5               3  262.794745
5     6               3  341.404788
```

Comment: I'm getting a 'math domain error' with this code

Comment: yes that could be due to the formula, i'm not sure if the input values like `ch[i]` etc are correct. My simple table seems to work

Comment: The input values are just the 'Band' and the 'Antenna_Height'

Comment: Is it possible you have a value of 0 or NaN in 'Antenna_Height'?

Comment: yes, there are some 0 or NaN values

Comment: `math.log10(0)` produces `ValueError: math domain error`

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem ! It's working now :)

Answer (score 1):

The pandas' way of applying a function to many rows is with `pd.apply`. I'm using `index=1` to get the values horizontally through both columns 'Antenna_Height' and 'Band':

```
def get_color(row):
    L = 8.4
    ch = 0.8 + (1.1*math.log10(row['Band']) - 0.7)*row['Antenna_Height'] - 1.56*math.log10(row['Band'])
    d = ((L - 69.55 - 26.16*math.log10(row['Band']) + 13.82*math.log10(row['Antenna_Height']) + ch)/(44.9 - 6.55*math.log10(row['Antenna_Height'])))**10
    return d

madrid['Color'] = madrid.apply(get_color, axis = 1)
```

This is not [necessarily faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938318/why-apply-sometimes-isnt-faster-than-for-loop-in-a-pandas-dataframe), but in general makes the intention of the code more obvious.